# Finding a clever pivot in a quicksort algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion

So I'm trying to implement a type of quicksort where instead of picking a random pivot, it picks a clever pivot each time. To do this it splits the array into groups of 5 and then sorts and finds the median of each group then takes all the medians found and finds the median of medians which will be the pivot. In theory the algorithm is supposed to have a O(n) running time. Here's what I have right now. The size of the array is defined by left and right.

```
    private static int pickCleverPivot(int left, int right, int[] A){
    int index=0;
    int n = right-left;
    if (n<=5) {
        Arrays.sort(A);
        return A[n/2];
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < n/5; i++) {
        A[i] = A[i];    
    }

        if (A[index] < A[n/5]){
            index = partition(n/5, right, A, index); 
        } else {
            index = partition(left, n/5, A, index); 
        }   
    System.out.println(index);
    return index;  
}
```

Here's the partition method:

```
private static int partition(int left, int right, int[] array, int pIndex){
        //move pivot to last index of the array
        swap(array,pIndex,right);

        int p=array[right];
        int l=left;
        int r=right-1;

        while(l<=r){
            while(l<=r && array[l]<=p){
                l++;
            }
            while(l<=r && array[r]>=p){
                r--;
            }
            if (l<r){
                swap(array,l,r);
            }
        }

        swap(array,l,right);
        return l;
    }
```

The problem is when I run this, it doesn't seem to do anything. The program seems to stop working while running the code. I think the main problem is with the for loop that splits the array into groups of 5 but I'm not sure about how these groups are stored so you can find the median of each group.

Comment: What is your actual question? I don't find any explanation what's wrong.

Comment: Well whenever I run it it's supposed to read a set of values and the output is supposed to be a sorted array. The problem is when I run the code it just says it's reading the values and nothing else happens there. So it's clearly not working as intended.

Comment: @David Rolfe: Okay, and did your debugger give you any clues as to where and why it might have gotten stuck?

Comment: @DavidRolfe, statement "int n = left+right;" seems wrong to me.

Comment: @DavidRolfe please see if you are satisfied by any answer

Comment: @DavidRolfe I just decribed your current problem and also suggested a solution, please have a look

Comment: Why would you want to do something that takes (and should ideally take) O(1) time in O(n) time?

Comment: You present uncommented code. I can't see it resemble the description given above (bottom-up median-of-medians?). Check what happens if `left+right <= 5`. Re-think how to handle the intermediate results: what is to happen to the values that were at `A[i]` before assigning a picked pivot?

Comment: Wiki article shows an inplace (it swaps the medians to the left of the array) version of [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians#Algorithm).

Comment: I just updated my code where if the length is less than or equal to 5 then it sorts that array and returns the middle value which is the pivot. The problem with that is when I run it on an array of size 5 or less it gives me an out of bounds exception.

Comment: `when I run this` - how, _exactly_? `if the length is less than or equal to 5 then it sorts that array and returns the middle value` just before `when I run it on an array of size 5 or less it gives me an out of bounds exception` again, _exactly how_ do you _run it_? Do you use an IDE, do you get a stack trace, is that any use to you? Is parameter `right` intended to be the largest valid index or exactly one beyond?

Comment: (Advice: Start over (keeping the current attempt). Start by writing down, as source/doc comments, _what exactly_ shall be achieved, and how. Think about how you can test if each piece on its own and everything together works as specified.)

Comment: I do know what exactly I want to achieve I just have no idea how to implement it into java. Basically the exact steps are start with the case if n<5. In that case I sort the array and find the pivot of that one array. Then when n>5, I'll divide the array into n/5 groups of 5 (possibly less for the last group). Then I run a for loop from 1 to n/5 where I sort each of the subgroups and find the median. Once I find the medians of all the subgroups I collect all 5 medians and then return pickCleverPivot(left, left+(n/5), A).

Comment: The problems I'm having are dividing the array into groups of 5 and finding the medians of each group and then collecting all the medians that I've found. I know the exact steps of how to do this but I just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: The first question I have is how do I split an array into groups of 5? Do I create a bunch of new arrays (for each group) and then sort each array to find the median? Also once I've found each median, how do I group each median together again so I can find the median of medians?

Comment: (This exchange is bound to exceed what comments are good for - join [How to find the median of medians](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124601/how-to-find-the-median-of-medians), or don't.)

Answer (score 3):

Your infinite recursion is here:

```
if (n<=5) {
    return (pickCleverPivot(0, left-1, A));
}
for(int i = 1; i < n/5; i++) {
    A[i] = pickCleverPivot(i, 5, A);    
}
```

If `n <= 5`, pickCleverPivot() will always call itself in the if branch. If `n > 5`, pickCleverPivot() will always call itself at least once in the for loop.

Comment: Ok I just updated my code where if n<=5 then I sort that one chunk and return the middle value of the sorted array. The problem is when I run the code on an array of size 5 or less I get an out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 1):

pickCleverPivot() seems to be not having a base condition, because of which recursion does not stop.

This causes stackoverflow of memory and hence your code doesn't seem to do anything.

Also I think if you are using median of medians approach to find pivot, you might want to look into the logic once. Your pickCleverPivot() does not seem to be doing exactly the same thing.

You might want to use this instead-

```
int MedianOfMedian(int arr[], int l, int r, int k)
{
// If k is smaller than number of elements in array
if (k > 0 && k <= r - l + 1)
{
    int n = r-l+1; // Number of elements in arr[l..r]

    // Divide arr[] in groups of size 5, calculate median
    // of every group and store it in median[] array.
    int i, median[(n+4)/5]; // There will be floor((n+4)/5) groups;
    for (i=0; i<n/5; i++)
        median[i] = findMedian(arr+l+i*5, 5);
    if (i*5 < n) //For last group with less than 5 elements
    {
        median[i] = findMedian(arr+l+i*5, n%5);
        i++;
    }

    // Find median of all medians using recursive call.
    // If median[] has only one element, then no need
    // of recursive call
    int medOfMed = (i == 1)? median[i-1]:
                             MedianOfMedian(median, 0, i-1, i/2);

    // Partition the array around a random element and
    // get position of pivot element in sorted array
    int pos = partition(arr, l, r, medOfMed);

    // If position is same as k
    if (pos-l == k-1)
        return arr[pos];
    if (pos-l > k-1)  // If position is more, recur for left
        return MedianOfMedian(arr, l, pos-1, k);

    // Else recur for right subarray
    return MedianOfMedian(arr, pos+1, r, k-pos+l-1);
    }

// If k is more than number of elements in array
return INT_MAX;
}
```

This is the findMedian function :

```
int findMedian(int arr[], int n)
{
sort(arr, arr+n);  // Sort the array
return arr[n/2];   // Return middle element
}
```